# glassfish response not getting in gzip compressed

Tags: java, glassfish, compression, gzip

i am working on java with Netbeans IDE and glassfish 3.1.2 i have created in rest services using jaxrs. when request from client is made ,i need to send json data in compressed format.to do this i have enabled the compression in glassfish as shown the following picture

[image]

but response got from the server is not compressed using gzip. it is receiving as normal json data. what should i do to overcome this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for GF 3.1.2.2.

Responses to HTTP requests in version 1.0 are not compressed. You must send your requests in **HTTP 1.1** to get gzipped responses from your glassfish server.

More over, you must add the header **"Accept-Encoding: gzip"** in your http requests.

Answer (score 0):

To get a compressed response you need to have both sides agree to use it.  You have configured GlassFish to send compressed responses.  I can see that from the picture.

You need to make sure that your request to the services tells GlassFish that it can accept a compressed response.  You normally do this by adding the following header to your HTTP requests: Accept-Encoding.  You can read about the header in the [RFC document that defines HTTP 1.1 request headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

You can also get a lot of info from reading though [SO questions about Accept-Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=accept-encoding).